# How to remove app-engine plugin from Grails project

Tags: grails, plugins

I develop project named

> MyProject

. I made a copy of this project -

> MyProject.zip

I wanted to to use

> app-engine

plugin, so I installed it and I got an error:

> No Google AppEngine SDK specified. Either set APPENGINE_HOME in your
>   environment or specify google.appengine.sdk in your
>   grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy file

Doesn't matter. Now, I do not want to use this plugin. Whatever I do, it prints me this same error. I removed project and I extracted my zip file.

Still, is the same problem. Could you explain, how to remove permanently plugin from grails? I use MacOS

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove project copy from `.grails`:

```
rm -rf ~/.grails/%GRAILS VERSION%/projects/MyProject
```